# rabbitmq start error:init terminating in do_boot ()

Tags: linux, erlang, rabbitmq

my environment is uBuntu16.04,erlang v7.3.when i start rabbitmq server,i got this error

```
{
    "init terminating in do_boot",
    {
        {
            badmatch,
                {
                    error,
                        {
                            edge,
                                {
                                    bad_vertex,inets
                                },
                            mochiweb,inets
                        }
                }
            },
            [
            {
                rabbit_plugins,calculate_dependencies,3,[]
            },
            {
                rabbit_prelaunch,prepare_plugins,3,[]
            },
            {
                rabbit_prelaunch,start,0,[]
            },
            {
                init,start_it,1,[]
            },
            {
                init,start_em,1,[]}
            ]
        }
    }
```